# reading all lines from client in C

Tags: c, string, sockets, client, readline

I want to read and process all lines from the clients but it seems like only one line is being read at a time. I thought having a loop while there is read data would read it all but it doesn't seem to be the case.
If the read is incomplete, I will continue it off at that index in the next step.

I have something like this:

```
if (select(maxfd + 1, &fdlist, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
    perror("select");
} else {
    if (FD_ISSET(listenfd, &fdlist)) {
        newclientconnection();
    }

    // see which clients have activity
    for (p = head; p; p = p->next) {
        if (FD_ISSET(p->fd, &fdlist)) {
            // want to read all lines from client
            while ((n = read(p->fd, p->buf + lastindex, MAX-p->lastindex) > 0) {
                p->lastindex += n;          
            }
            if (n==0) {
                removeclient(p);
            } 

            // want to process all the lines
            process(p->buf);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have blocking in this line:

```
while ((n = read(p->fd, p->buf + lastindex, MAX-p->lastindex) > 0))
```

On the last iteration, the `while` cond. waits for input from `read`. but the input already read. so, waiting for new input.

If you assume that you gona get data bigger than buffer (therefore you put `read` into `while` condition), you need to define timeout  (`select` etc) for `read` **OR** define special symbol ("\r\n\r\n" for example) to determine "this is end of the  data". Otherwise, the `while` loop will wait forever for more data.

Comment: Or make the file descriptor non-blocking with O_NONBLOCK?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Of course! there is several options, that why i wrote "etc".